# Error after changing primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I’m building a WPF application using .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6.0 to map C# objects to a SQL Server 2008 database. I'm getting a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` like this:

> SqlException: The column name 'InstructionID' is specified more than once in the SET clause

The exception is for each property / column in the target table, and has only come about after I dropped and recreated the target database table to use an identity based int primary key after having originally defined the primary key as a `varchar` data type.

My original C# class and table were as follows. This configuration worked without error:

```
public class UnitInstruction 
{
    [Key] public string instructionID { get; set; }
    public int? unitID { get; set; }
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class UnitInstructionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UnitInstruction>
{
    public UnitInstructionMap()
    {
        ToTable("UnitInstructions");
        HasKey(i => i.InstructionID);
        Property(i => i.InstructionID).HasColumnName("InstructionID");
        Property(i => i.UnitID).HasColumnName("UnitID");
        Property(i => i.PropertyOne).HasColumnName("PropertyOne");
        Property(i => i.PropertyTwo).HasColumnName("PropertyTwo");
    }
}


CREATE TABLE [RealEstate].[UnitInstructions](
    [InstructionID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [UnitID] [int] NULL,
    [PropertyOne] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PropertyTwo] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CommercialRealEstate.RetailUnitInstructions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstructionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The errors happen with this version...

```
public class UnitInstruction {
    [Key] public int id { get; set; }
    public string instructionID { get; set; }
    public int? unitID { get; set; }
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }
}


public class UnitInstructionDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UnitInstruction> UnitInstructions { get; set; }
    public UnitInstructionDbContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UnitInstructionDbContext>(null);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("RealEstate");
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UnitInstructionMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class UnitInstructionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UnitInstruction>
{
    public UnitInstructionMap()
    {
        ToTable("UnitInstructions");
        HasKey(i => i.ID);
        Property(i => i.InstructionID).HasColumnName("InstructionID");
        Property(i => i.UnitID).HasColumnName("UnitID");
        Property(i => i.PropertyOne).HasColumnName("PropertyOne");
        Property(i => i.PropertyTwo).HasColumnName("PropertyTwo");
    }
}


CREATE TABLE [RealEstate].[UnitInstructions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InstructionID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [UnitID] [int] NULL,
    [PropertyOne] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PropertyTwo] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CommercialRealEstate.RetailUnitInstructions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is there any hidden file that needs to also be updated within EF to enable the new configuration to work? I’m only editing code directly in VS2017, without the use of any modelling tools or wizards etc within the IDE.

Comment: Are you dropping the existing tables before you are Creating? Usually I find I have to close SSMS between Dropping and Creating.

Comment: Yes, I am dropping the existing tables before creating - there are no errors reported to SSMS from SQL Server at any point either.

Comment: Then you must be calling the code twice without dropping the table(s).  The error indicates you are trying to add a column with the same name twice in the same table.

Comment: show us the code that triggers the inserts. Also, when you say `HasKey(x => x.ID)` you don't need to add `Property(x => x.ID)`

Comment: Do you have any related entities that have a FK back to the UnitInstructions? These mappings may need to be changed over to map to the ID column rather than InstructionID. If references still point to that column it may possibly confuse EF into thinking a PK called InstructionID should be on the table.

Comment: Steve Py - yes the UnitID is a FK for the ID of a RetailUnit entity. I've not declared this referential integrity in the database yet as I am just prototyping